# Can't connect Node.js to Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm newbie about node.js and MongoDB.

I have installed MongoDB on a server A. MongoDB is running and port 27017 is opened. I am able to connect to robo3T

I have a Node.js app on another server B. Node.js is running.

When I access the website, everything is displayed correctly but when I want to login (so it needs MongoDB access), the website turns and get this error: Cannot GET /502.shtml

Here are all details

Mongodb server
 mongod.conf :

```
port: 27017
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Nodejs app.js:

```
    var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://XXXX:27017/preprod', {useMongoClient: true}, function(err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);});
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

XXXX = address IP of server A (mongodb server)

when I run app.js I got this error

```
name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [XXX:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT XXXX:27017]' }
```

I am able to connect from my linux machine, other VPS server but not to my nodejs server!

Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Did you restart the MongoDB daemon (mongod) after making changes in the mongod.conf?

Comment: Yes! I am able to connect to robo3T but not able to connect to nodejs server. here is the error message: 'failed to connect to server [ipAdressOfServerA:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT ipAdressOfServerA:27017]' }

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. You need to restart you mongod service after making changes to the `mongod.conf` file. Do it like this on a ubuntu machine, `sudo service mongod restart` and tell what happens.

Comment: Yes I restarted mongod. and i got the same error

Comment: If you're running mongodb (server A), you should check if it is mongod's port 27017 is open or not using iptables

Comment: yes it's opened. Actually, after investigation, the problem is coming from server B (nodejs server). this server doesn't allow mongodb to connect. the question is which port should I open on server B. any idea?

Comment: Server B doesn't need to have any ports open, since it will act as client to Server A. Are you running your Server A on a EC2 instance? or any other platform?

Comment: VPS (A2hosting) platform

Comment: Here, follow this official tutorial to get port open on your VPS: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

Comment: yes already done :)

Comment: Kindly add the `iptables` command you used to your question.

Comment: Done :) I have added the iptables content to the question

Comment: Change XXXX's value from Server A's IP to 0.0.0.0 and check

Comment: should I keep /32 like this 0.0.0.0/32?

Comment: You can keep it that way or remove it, hardly matters

Comment: same error in my console nodejs : 
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [XXXX:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT XXXX:27017]

Comment: One moment I checked iptables files and got 4 lines. let me remove lines with XXXX ip address and keep those with 0.0.0.0 and save the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

Actually the port 27017 was closed on my nodejs server.
now it can connected!

if it can help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Do this on a Linux machine,

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0 -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 0.0.0.0 -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and try connecting from the remote server (Server B) with the IP address of Server A.

Comment: ok how can I connect from the remote server (Server B) with the IP address of Server A. is there any command

Comment: Yes, let's say your Server A IP is `Y.Y.Y.Y`, and database name is `mydb`, then the command would be, `mongo Y.Y.Y.Y/mydb`

Comment: message: 'failed to connect to server [XXXX:27017] on first connect

Comment: I don't understand why my server mongodb able to connect to robo3t but not to nodejs server. Then I think the problem is coming from server nodejs. firewall are closed on nodejs server. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you share your `iptables.firewall.rules` file's content?

Comment: could you please see the question. I have updated the content

Comment: Try this, `mongo --host X.X.X.X:27017`. Also kindly remove the **firewall.rules** file content from the question. You have exposed your IP address.

Comment: on my nodejs server right? actually on my server it says "-bash: mongo: command not found"

Comment: yeah, on your node.js server or your local linux machine.

Comment: you need to have mongo installed there as well for communication.

Comment: question updated. can't connect from my machine to the server even if mongodb is running

Comment: actually i can't install mongodb on my nodejs server. this server doesn't support mongodb that's why I have another one which supports mongodb

Comment: Have you tried using Node.js driver to connect to the MongoDB instance?

Comment: hum do you mean this ? npm install mongodb --save

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost:27017/<project_name>, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

Where  is the name of the project.

Make sure you've installed and imported mongoose. And also, that you've got mongod running.

Also, I'd remove 'var promise = ' before mongoose.connect(..)